# DbContext is already Disposed AutoFac

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

i already googled for a while to find my problem. I already read a topic inside stackoverlow about dbcontext and autofac , but i would realize if my problem is different.

I have a **Web API with EF6 codeFirst** with autofac as IOC.
My problem is that inside a logger i have some exception of this type :

**"The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed."**

It's happens most of times insided a **custom ActionFilterAttribute** with use a unitofWork

I have different implementation of unitofwork cause i have different db.

```
    .....
   // register dependencies
        builder.Register<DotNetCache>(u => new DotNetCache())
            .As<ICache>()
            .InstancePerRequest();

        builder.Register<UnitOfWork>(u => new UnitOfWork())
            .As<IUnitOfWork>()
            .InstancePerRequest();

        builder.Register<AdoUnitOfWork>(u => new AdoUnitOfWork())
            .InstancePerRequest();

        builder.Register<PrefAdoUnitOfWork>(u => new PrefAdoUnitOfWork())
            .InstancePerRequest();

    ......
```

Any idea becouse it could happens?

Thanks

UPDATE : inside ActionFilterAttribute i ovveride OnActionExecuting and OnActionExecuted

**StackTrace:**

```
System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult+<ExecuteAsync>d__0 in MoveNext  
:Void MoveNext()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1 in GetResult  : TResult GetResult()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter in HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification : Void HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter in ThrowForNonSuccess at : Void ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult+<ExecuteAsync>d__2 in MoveNext at : Void MoveNext()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1 in GetResult at line : TResult GetResult()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter in HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification : Void HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter in ThrowForNonSuccess : Void ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute+<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0 in MoveNext  : Void MoveNext()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter in HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification :Void HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter in ThrowForNonSuccess  : Void ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute in OnActionExecutingAsync : System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnActionExecutingAsync(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
LanguageAttribute in OnActionExecuting  : Void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext)
System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions in Query  : System.Linq.IQueryable`1[T] Query[T](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[T])
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1 in Query  :System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[TResult] Query  ()
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1 in Query System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.IInternalQuery`1[TEntity] Query ()
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1 in CreateObjectQuery :System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[TEntity] CreateObjectQuery(Boolean, System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean], System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbExecutionStrategy)
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext in get_ObjectContext :System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext get_ObjectContext()
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext in InitializeContext : Void InitializeContext()
```

Comment: Could you share the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: do you have async/await code in your `OnActionExecuted` / `OnActionExecuting` ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand Nope , i cant understand why it uses async

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to reproduce the issue. Could you describe share the code of your attribute and the whole registration process ? Are you using the [Autofac.WebApi2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.WebApi2/) nuget package as described in the [documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html) ?